# How do I parse the elements in this list?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list to parse, (but I am finding a generic way to parse any list like this):

`dev-libs/icu-63.1-r1 alpha amd64 arm arm64 ia64 ppc ppc64 x86 hppa s390 
dev-libs/icu-layoutex-63.1 alpha amd64 ia64 ppc ppc64 x86 hppa sparc
dev-lang/perl-5.28-r1 s390
virtual/ruby_gems-0.3_pre24 amd64 x86`

This seems to fall sometimes, because it tries the parse the architectures list like starting with `alpha` till the end of line, but I really want to ignore everything after a package version but leave the posibility of space existence after a version.

My code is following: (print stuff just for debug)

```
for line in args.list:
    print(line)
    package_category = re.search(r'((?<==)\w+-\w+|\w+-\w+|\w+)', line).group(0)
    print(package_category)
    package_name = re.search(r'(?<=/)[a-z]+.[a-z]+', line).group(0)
    print(package_name)
    package_version = re.search(r'(?<=-)\d+.\d-*\w*\s?', line).group(0)
```

I expect this to do following:

package_category variable should contain a category like:

`dev-libs
dev-lang
virtual`

package_name should contain a package name, like:

`icu
 icu-layoutex
 perl
 ruby_gems`

package_version:

`63.1-r1
 63.1
 0.3_pre24`

the rest should be just ignored

currently I suddenly hit the architrctures list somehow with the output:

`dev-libs/icu-63.1-r1
dev-libs
icu
alpha
alpha
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./repomator.py", line 47, in <module>
    package_name = re.search(r'(?<=/)[a-z]+.[a-z]+', line).group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: I ran your code and it gave me exactly what you expect. Where are you failing?

Comment: Why not a list of `package_category` that contains all the strings before `/` and a list of `package_name` that contains all the strings after `/` but before second occurrence of `-`and a list of `package_version` that contains all the strings after second occurrence of `-` and before empty `" "`

Comment: @Aaron_ab I've edited the OP to include the error I hit

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want:

```
(?P<category>\w+(?:-\w+)?)/(?P<name>[a-z]+(?:[-_][a-z]+)?)-(?P<version>\S+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LbsQ4j/1)

**Explanation:**

```
(?<category>            # named group category
  \w+                   # 1 or more word character
  (?:-\w+)?             # optional, a dash then 1 or more word character
)                       # end group
/                       # a slash
(?<name>                # named group name
  [a-z]+                # 1 or more alpha
  (?:[-_][a-z]+)?       # optional, dash or underscore and 1 or more alpha
)                       # end group
-                       # a dash
(?<version>             # named group version
  \S+                   # 1 or more non space character
)                       # end group
```

**code:**

```
import re

list = [
'dev-libs/icu-63.1-r1 alpha amd64 arm arm64 ia64 ppc ppc64 x86 hppa s390 ',
'dev-libs/icu-layoutex-63.1 alpha amd64 ia64 ppc ppc64 x86 hppa sparc',
'dev-lang/perl-5.28-r1 s390',
'virtual/ruby_gems-0.3_pre24 amd64 x86'
]
for line in list:
    res = re.search(r'(?P<category>\w+(?:-\w+)?)/(?P<name>[a-z]+(?:[-_][a-z]+)?)-(?P<version>\S+)', line)
    print "cat: ",res.group('category'),"\t  name: ",res.group('name'), "\t\tversion: ",res.group('version')
```

**Output:**

```
cat:  dev-libs    name:  icu        version:  63.1-r1
cat:  dev-libs    name:  icu-layoutex       version:  63.1
cat:  dev-lang    name:  perl       version:  5.28-r1
cat:  virtual     name:  ruby_gems      version:  0.3_pre24
```

Comment: hmm, regex itself works, but when I try to assign the results into dictonary like this (for the further use):

```packages.append({
            "category": res.group('category'),
            "name": res.group('name'),
            "version": res.group('version')
        })```

I got error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Why does it try to perform search again, if this is already in group? :(

Comment: @MishaLavrov: I don't know too much python, but, I think dictionary haven't append method. And how do you use it? Are you doing the assignmentinside or outside the for loop?  **Inside** the for loop, just add `packages["category"] = res.group('category')`, same for name and version. I've just tried it and it works fine.